# Cannot get Spring-MVC @Async to go to a different thread

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous

I am trying to get a method to run async in my Spring MVC web application.
I have added these lines to my config.

```
<!-- Enable Scheduling/Async Annotations -->
<task:executor id="villageExecutor" pool-size="5"/>
<task:scheduler id="villageScheduler" pool-size="5"/>
<task:annotation-driven executor="villageExecutor" scheduler="villageScheduler" />
```

I've added the @Async to my method like so;

```
@Component
public class OutstandingBreakdownDownload {
 private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(OutstandingBreakdownDownload.class.getName());

 @Async
 public void execute(String companyNumber) {
   System.out.println("Execute method asynchronously. " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

And I am calling this method from a servlet like so;

```
System.out.println("Initial thread. " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
new OutstandingBreakdownDownload().execute(companyNumber);
```

When I check the logs the thread the servlet is running in is the same as the thread the @Async method is running.  I see no error messages at all.
I also use the @Schedule annotation and this works correctly as I see those running in villageSheduler threads.

This is the output from the console when I call the @Async method.

```
Initial thread. http-bio-8080-exec-10
Execute method asynchronously. http-bio-8080-exec-10
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create the objects using `new` for the classes which are annotated with `@Component`, `@Controller`, `@Service` as the objects (by default singleton scope) are managed/injected by the Spring container.

Rather, in your servlet class,  add `@Autowired` for `OutstandingBreakdownDownload` so that Spring container can run the Async method in a separate thread.

```
public class Servlet ... {

   @Autowired
   private OutstandingBreakdownDownload downloadBean;

   //your methods
   public R method1() {
     downloadBean.execute();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The component with `@Async` annotation needs to be injected by Spring, not created internally with a constructor.

When an object of a component class (ie. annotated with `@Component`, `@Service` etc.) is instantiated with a constructor, it behaves just like a plain class. Spring does not change its behavior. To make use of Spring annotations it is necessary to let Spring instantiate the component and *inject* it to objects that use it.
For example:

```
public class MyServlet implements Servlet {
    @Autowired
    private OutstandingBreakdownDownload outstandingBreakdownDownload;
    //...
    public void someMethod() {
        //...
        outstandingBreakdownDownload.execute(companyNumber);    
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am new to Spring MVC, can you explain how I inject this by Spring?

Comment: Use @Autowired as described in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You calling method `OutstandingBreakdownDownload` is not injected by Spring since you explicitly created an instance of it.

You have to let Spring manage it by autowiring it:

```
@Autowired
private OutstandingBreakdownDownload outstandingBreakdownDownload;

System.out.println("Initial thread. " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
outstandingBreakdownDownload.execute(companyNumber);
```